# Export vectors from fastText to spaCy

Tags: spacy

I downloaded the [fasttext.cc](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html) vectors of 1.5gb, I used example code [spaCy examples vectors_fast_text](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/vectors_fast_text.py). I executed the following command in the terminal:

```
python config/vectors_fast_text.py vectors_loc data/vectors/wiki.pt.vec
```

After a few minutes with the processor at 100%, I received the following text:

> class colspan 0.32231358

What happens from here? How can I export these vectors elsewhere, such as for example with my AWS S3 training templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the example script, to load the existing data of my language, read the file word2vec and at the end write all the content in a folder (this folder needs to exist).

Follow vectors_fast_text.py:

> [LANGUAGE] = example: "pt"
>
> [FILE_WORD2VEC] = "./data/word2vec.txt"

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import plac
import numpy

import spacy
from spacy.language import Language


@plac.annotations()
def main():
    nlp = spacy.load('[LANGUAGE]')
    with open("[FILE_WORD2VEC]", 'rb') as file_:
        header = file_.readline()
        nr_row, nr_dim = header.split()
        nlp.vocab.reset_vectors(width=int(nr_dim))
        count = 0
        for line in file_:
            count += 1
            line = line.rstrip().decode('utf8')
            pieces = line.rsplit(' ', int(nr_dim))
            word = pieces[0]
            print("{} - {}".format(count, word))
            vector = numpy.asarray([float(v) for v in pieces[1:]], dtype='f')
            nlp.vocab.set_vector(word, vector)  # add the vectors to the vocab
    nlp.to_disk("./models/new_nlp/")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    plac.call(main)
```

Type in the terminal:

```
python vectors_fast_text.py
```

It will take about 10 minutes to finish, depending on the size of the word2vec file. In the script I made the print of the word, so that you can follow.

After that, you must type in the terminal:

```
python -m spacy package ./models/new_nlp/ ./my_models/
python setup.py sdist
```

And then you will have a "zip" file.

```
pip install /path/to/pt_example_model-1.0.0.tar.gz
```

---

A detailed tutorial can be found on the spaCy website:
https://spacy.io/usage/training