# Export fasttext vectors (korean) from fastText to spacy (UnicodeDecodeError)

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy, fasttext, spacy-3

Hi everyone i downloaded the korean fasttext model from [FastText Korean Model](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html) and tried to export it to spacy using this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import plac
import numpy

import spacy
from spacy.language import Language


@plac.annotations()
def main():
    nlp = spacy.blank('ko')
    with open("ko.vec", 'rb') as file_:
        header = file_.readline()
        nr_row, nr_dim = header.split()
        nlp.vocab.reset_vectors(width=int(nr_dim))
        count = 0
        for line in file_:
            count += 1
            line = line.rstrip().decode("utf-8")
            pieces = line.rsplit(' ', int(nr_dim))
            word = pieces[0]
            print("{} - {}".format(count, word))
            vector = numpy.asarray([float(v) for v in pieces[1:]], dtype='f')
            nlp.vocab.set_vector(word, vector)  # add the vectors to the vocab
    nlp.to_disk("/models/new_nlp/")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    plac.call(main)
```

this code i got from this answered question on stackoverflow:
[Export FastText from fasttext to spacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49663387/export-vectors-from-fasttext-to-spacy)

But after executing the code i got this error at the end:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\fasttexttospacy\fasttexttospacy.py", line 31, in <module>
    plac.call(main)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\fasttexttospacy\lib\site-packages\plac_core.py", line 436, in call
    cmd, result = parser.consume(arglist)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\fasttexttospacy\lib\site-packages\plac_core.py", line 287, in consume
    return cmd, self.func(*(args + varargs + extraopts), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\fasttexttospacy\fasttexttospacy.py", line 21, in main
    line = line.rstrip().decode("utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

I don't really understand where the problem is, can somebody explain me why i get this error please? It's not clear to me.

Comment: As general a debugging tactic, try breaking the offending line into separate steps so that the step triggering the error (the `.decode()`) is on its own line, & doesn't re-assign into the same input variable (in this case `line`). Then, try wrapping that line in a `try…catch` block, that when the error occurs prints out extra useful info: especially the value of the `line` being decodes itself, and the `count` has a hint of line-number. Then you can look more closely at just that line, to see if it's unique, or needs different handling by your code.

Comment: Encoding problems can be hard to debug, perhaps the encoding in your file is not really `utf-8`. Try to use a simple editor like Notepad++ to open it, go to Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8 and save as a different file. Then try to load that file and see if your problem persists. Generally if your file is UTF-8 it might make more sense to use `open("ko.vec", 'rb', encoding="utf-8")` instead of decoding each individual line.